# Retrieve firebaseUID from user_pseudo_id

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, userid

I have an `analytics` table that contains recorded events. These events are recorded by Firebase and exported to BigQuery. I need to connect this table of events that identify users through their `user_pseudo_ID` with another table that just contains `userUID` and `firebaseUID`.

I was not able to find a documentation or a topic describing how to connect this `user_pseudo_id` with `userUID` or `firebaseUID`.

Do you know how to do that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase does not automatically set a identifiable user ID for analytics events. Instead it sets an internal ID that merely identifies what events come from the same user, not who they are. If you want to tie the events to a user of your app, you'll have to set the user ID in the application code. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid

This will add your User ID to the analytics events, and you can then use that in the BigQuery export to tie the events to users in your own tables.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. Then is it too late to identify the users associated with the events that have already occurred?